# Como criptografar usando um algoritmo de criptografia assimétrico no Delphi?

Tags: delphi, criptografia

Como criptografar usando um algoritmo de criptografia assimétrico no Delphi?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Existe um componente chamado [TChilkatCrypt2](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/delphiCrypt2Ref.html). Trabalhei bastante tempo com ele. Segue um trecho de código de como assinar um arquivo com uma chave privada e verifica-lo com uma chave pública:

```
//
//  Passo 1: Assinar Arquivo
//

uses
    Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
    Dialogs, StdCtrls,
    CHILKATCRYPT2Lib_TLB,
    CHILKATDSALib_TLB,
    OleCtrls;

...

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
success: Integer;
crypt: TChilkatCrypt2;
hashStr: PWideChar;
dsa: TChilkatDsa;
pemPrivateKey: PWideChar;
hexSig: PWideChar;
dsa2: TChilkatDsa;
pemPublicKey: PWideChar;

begin


//  Usar Chilkat Crypt para gerar um hash a partir de um arquivo.
crypt := TChilkatCrypt2.Create(Self);

//Este componente é pago, você deve fazer isso para usa-lo como trial
success := crypt.UnlockComponent('Anything for 30-day trial'); 
if (success <> 1) then
  begin
    ShowMessage(crypt.LastErrorText);
    Exit;
  end;

crypt.EncodingMode := 'hex';
crypt.HashAlgorithm := 'sha-1';

// Retornar o SHA-1 do arquivo.
hashStr := crypt.HashFileENC('arquivo.xml'); //Por exemplo...

dsa := TChilkatDsa.Create(Self);

//  Os componentes Chilkat Crypt e o Chilkat DSA são produtos
//  distintos. Prefira comprar o "Chilkat Bundle", isso 
//  libera os demais produtos e fica mais em conta.
success := dsa.UnlockComponent('Anything for 30-day trial');
if (success <> 1) then
  begin
    ShowMessage(dsa.LastErrorText);
    Exit;
  end;

//  Carregar a chave privada a partir do arquivo PEM
pemPrivateKey := dsa.LoadText('dsa_privada.pem');
success := dsa.FromPem(pemPrivateKey);
if (success <> 1) then
  begin
    ShowMessage(dsa.LastErrorText);
    Exit;
  end;

//  Opcionalmente você pode verificar se a chave é válida
success := dsa.VerifyKey();
if (success <> 1) then
  begin
    ShowMessage(dsa.LastErrorText);
    Exit;
  end;

//  Carregar o hash a ser assinado
success := dsa.SetEncodedHash('hex',hashStr);
if (success <> 1) then
  begin
    ShowMessage(dsa.LastErrorText);
    Exit;
  end;

//  Aqui mais objeto contém a chave privada e o hash. Está pronto
//  para criar a assinatura.
success := dsa.SignHash();
if (success <> 1) then
  begin
    ShowMessage(dsa.LastErrorText);
    Exit;
  end;

//  Se ocorrer tudo certo, o objeto irá conter a assinatura. Podemos acessá-la 
//  como uma string cifrada em base64.

hexSig := dsa.GetEncodedSignature('hex');
Memo1.Lines.Add('Signature:');
Memo1.Lines.Add(hexSig);

//  -----------------------------------------------------------
//  Passo 2: Verificar a assinatura DSA
//  -----------------------------------------------------------

dsa2 := TChilkatDsa.Create(Self);

//  Carregar a chave pública utilizada para verificação.
pemPublicKey := dsa2.LoadText('dsa_publica.pem');
success := dsa2.FromPublicPem(pemPublicKey);
if (success <> 1) then
  begin
    ShowMessage(dsa2.LastErrorText);
    Exit;
  end;

//  Carregar o hash... 
success := dsa2.SetEncodedHash('hex',hashStr);
if (success <> 1) then
  begin
    ShowMessage(dsa2.LastErrorText);
    Exit;
  end;

//  Carregar a assinatura
success := dsa2.SetEncodedSignature('hex',hexSig);
if (success <> 1) then
  begin
    ShowMessage(dsa2.LastErrorText);
    Exit;
  end;

//  Verificar
success := dsa2.Verify();
if (success <> 1) then
  begin
    ShowMessage(dsa2.LastErrorText);
  end
else
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Assinatura Válida! YEAHHHH');
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 7):

Existe uma suíte de componentes chamada tpOnguard, que pode ser baixado neste **[link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tponguard/)** para delphi que tem diversas formas de permitir que você faça isso.

um exemplo abaixo permite gerar uma chave de 16 valores em Hexa (CodeString) (*e.g.* AF87-0E3B-57AA-16FF) baseada na identificação da máquina, número serial controlado por você (para controlar o número de licenças individuais do cliente) e a data de validade. Todas estas informações podem ser recuperadas utilizando a chave informada.

Ele utiliza como chave de criptografia um objeto do tipo **Tkey** que é um conjunto de valores hexadecimais. Estes valores te permitem gerenciar licenças para diferentes softwares/versões

```
procedure GerarRegistro; 
var 
  Chave: Tkey; 
  MachineMod: Integer; 
  Validade: TDate; 
  Serial: LongInt; 
  CodigoRegistro: TCode; 
  CodeString,valortemp: String; 
  I, valor : Integer; 
begin 
  try 
    MachineMod := StrToInt(txtIdMaquina.Text); 
  except 
    MensagemdeErro('Número Identificador do Computador não é valido'); 
    exit; 
  end; 
  try 
    Serial := StrToInt(txtSerial.Text) except MensagemdeErro 
      ('Número Serial informado não é valido'); 
    exit; 
  end; 
  if Length(cmbAplicativo.Text) = 0 then 
  begin 
    MensagemdeErro('Selecione o software do registro'); 
    exit; 
  end; 
  btnGerarRegistro.Enabled := false; 
  OgUtil.HexToBuffer(cmbAplicativo.KeyValue, Chave, sizeof(Chave)); 
  if chkValidade.Checked then 
    Validade := dtpValidade.Date 
  else 
    Validade := StrtoDate('31/12/2199'); 
  OgMakeKeys.SetKey(Chave); 
  OgMakeKeys.ApplyModifierToKey(MachineMod, Chave, sizeof(Chave)); 
  InitSerialNumberCode(Chave, Serial, Validade, CodigoRegistro); 
  CodeString := BufferToHex(CodigoRegistro, sizeof(CodigoRegistro)); 
  System.Insert('-', CodeString, 13); 
  System.Insert('-', CodeString, 09); 
  System.Insert('-', CodeString, 05); 
end;
```

Neste **[post](http://www.activedelphi.com.br/forum/viewtopic.php?p=304704&sid=299fe4f8e9337d7ab334748752e59057)** tem os fontes completos caso queria seguir o exemplo.